# Sceneform library works only with compileSDK set to 28

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

When I use samples of Google's Sceneform library to use ARCore features, they work as long as the target and compile SDK versions are set to 28, but not when I upgrade them to 33.
The problem occurs on my device MI 10i, but not on Samsung S9+, where I can upgrade the SDK version and still be able to achieve the AR experience without any issues.

I try to download the Sceneform library, upgrade it's build.gradle file, but the problem still persists.

Edit: I have tried with the versions 1.16.0 and 1.15.0 of Sceneform

Comment: Details about which version of which libraries you are using would be useful as Google's Sceneform library was open-sourced and other project forks exist.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I have just updated my description. Thanks!

Comment: The MI 10i came out after the Google Sceneform library was open-sourced so support has to come from the community. That said, I am aware of: https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android Be aware of changes from the original Google version.